# Javascript array calculation and transformation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently struggle to program a receipt calculator. I want to `map` over an array with a specific value, then round the numbers and convert they to a string with commas instead of dots.

```js
let ingredients = [0.02, 0.05, 0.5, 1.2];

let map = ingredients.map(x => x * 6);

for (let entry of map)
{
    entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
    console.log(entry);
}
```

This is what I get using a `quantity` of 6 on the mapping procedure:

```
0.12; 0.30000000000000004; 3; 7.199999999999999
```

But instead, I want it to be like:

```
0,12; 0,3; 3; 7,2
```

Comment: On a side note, it's written `ingredients`, not `ingridients`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to the precision problem you are facing when performing arithmetic operations with float numbers could be approached using a **correction factor**. A `correction factor` will be that number you need to multiply to the float number so that it gets converted into an integer. In this sense, all the arithmetic operations will now perform between integers numbers. You can check the next code to see how to use a `correction factor` in this particular case:

```js
let quantity = 6;
let ingredients = [0.02, 0.05, 0.5, 1.2];

// Define a correction factor for arithmetic operations within
// the set of float numbers available on ingredients.
let cf = Math.pow(10, 2);

let map = ingredients.map(x =>
{
    let res = (x * cf) * (quantity * cf) / (cf * cf);
    return res.toString().replace(".", ",");
});

let mapRounded = ingredients.map(x =>
{
    let res = (x * cf) * (quantity * cf) / (cf * cf);
    return Math.ceil(res);
});

console.log("Original: ", map, "Rounded-Up: ", mapRounded);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the must useful answer to my problem. Im now trying to implement that if map[2] has a comma (eg. 3,5) it should always round up to the next integer... like 4. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @aura199x you can create another map of rounded-up elements, with `Math.ceil()`. I have updated my answer, check if this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

`entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")` doesn't change the `entry` it `return` a new value.**You need to assign entry a new value.**

```js
let quantity = 4;

let ingridients = [ 0.02, 0.05, 0.5, 1.2 ];
let map = ingridients.map(x => x * quantity);

for (let entry of map) {
  entry = entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
  console.log(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");` doesn't change `entry`. You need to assign it to something.

```
let formatted = entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")
console.log( formatted )
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `.toFixed` and `replace` are *pure* (as any other method working with primitives) that means they do not change the referenced value itself but return a new value. If you'd do

```
console.log(entry.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
```

you would log the wanted returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ingridients = [ 0.02, 0.05, 0.5, 1.2 ];
let quantity = 6;

let map = ingridients
    .map(x => x * quantity)
    .map(n => n.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));

for (let entry of map) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

Comment: Is this the more elegant way? Or the answer from @Maheer Ali  ? Thanks